# prevent the back button after submitting form

Tags: php, xhtml

i am working on a contact form. nothing is stored in a database, just sends an email. I was wondering if there was a way to prevent the back button after i do a redirect to my thank you page. At the moment, if i press the back button, i see all the information entered to the form.

```
$send_mail = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
if ($send_mail) {
    header("Location: ../thankyou");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: No, you don't get to remove basic functions from software on someone else's computer.

Comment: Do you want to prevent back button functionality or just avoid showing the form information when the back button is pressed? You can modify cache options with headers, but I think modern browsers still do their particular caching (Safari in particular had some strange behaviours)

Answer (score 0):

You could save the user current location to session data and check from there if user is somewhere else than in the form page when pressing submit, and if he is, then redirect somewhere else rather than continue with submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer, but I'll leave this here as an idea - Perhaps some sort of "Are you sure you want to submit this form?" check? 
If they click Yes then great, send it (applies as a basic validation check the first time round too). If they say No cancel and stay on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could add prefixes to the form name like
     `<input name='<?= time(); ?>__secrets' type='text' />`
so using same browsare won't make visible previous entered data.

With javascript you can do some playng, like ajax submit the form then clear it or in the thank you page alter the back button functionality, see http://www.serpere.info/jquery-history-plugin/samples/ajax/